# Calculating the distance function and projection

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $\Omega=\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid\langle a,x\rangle=b\}$.

We define the distance function and projection as follows
$$d(x;\Omega)=\inf\{||x-\omega||\mid\omega\in\Omega\}$$
$$\pi(x;\Omega)=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid||x-\omega||=d(x;\Omega)\}$$
Suppose  we want to find $d(x;\Omega)$, that is
$$d(x;\Omega)=\inf\{||x-\omega||\mid\langle a,\omega\rangle=b\}$$
I used the method of Lagrange coefficients
$$f(\omega)=||x-\omega||,\quad g(\omega)=\langle a,\omega\rangle,\quad\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$$
and obtained that
$$\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\omega_i(x_i-\omega_i)}{b||x-\omega||}$$ 
I replaced $\lambda$ for example to
$$\frac{\omega_1-x_1}{||x-\omega||}+\lambda a_1=0$$
to find $\omega_1$
$$\omega_1-x_1+\frac{a_1x_1\omega_1^2}b+\frac{a_1}{b}\sum_{i=2}^n\omega_i(x_i-\omega_i)=0$$

So I couldn't arrive to any thing fun to use it for calculating the projection. This is an elementary exercise in first chapter of mordukhovich's book about convex analysis, so I can't use the advanced methods about it if exists!

Comment: Orthogonal projection onto a translated subspace is the same as closest point projection. That's true in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and its true in infinite-dimensional inner product space, too. You have a translated subspace of dimension $n-1$ assuming $a\ne 0$. You can translate the problem back to a subspace if you want by finding $x_{0}$ such that $(a,x_0)=b$ and noting that $(a,x-x_0)=0$ iff $(a,x)=b$.

Comment: @T.A.E. Sorry, but I couldn't understand any thing about your comment, just because I'm not very familiar to advanced methods in convex analysis, as well as I mentioned in question now, this is just an elementary exercise in the first chapter of Mordukhovich's book about convex analysis!

Comment: You can use \mid for the vertical bar in the middle of a set : \{ x \mid ...\}

Comment: @ThibautDumont Thanks for your suggestion :)

Comment: Do you remember from Calculus that in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, the closest-point projection of $x$ onto a line, plane is the same as the orthgonal projection. That is, if $M$ is a line or a plane, and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, then the point $m \in M$ that is closest to $x$ is such that $x-m$ is orthogonal to the plane $M$? The same is true for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ using all translated subspaces of the form $y+S$ where $S$ is a subspace. The closest point to $x$ on the translated subspace $y+S$ is the unit $s \in S$ such that $(x-y-s)\perp S$.

Comment: And, using the fact that the normal to $\Omega$ has direction $a$, one readily arrives at $$d(x,\Omega)=\frac{\mid b-\langle a,x\rangle\mid}{\sqrt{\langle a,a\rangle}}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to apply multivariable calculus tools to the distance function, it's best to use the *squared* distance function:
$$f(\omega)=\|x-\omega\|^2,\quad g(\omega)=\langle a,\omega\rangle$$
The minimum is attained in the same place, but  this $f$ expands as inner product, allowing for simpler computations: $\nabla  f(\omega) = 2(\omega-x)$. So, the equation $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$ becomes
$$
2(\omega - x) = \lambda a
$$ 
From here you should solve for $\omega$, not for $\lambda$ (because this uses the full vector equation, rather than the 1st component as in your attempt): 
$$\omega = x+\frac{\lambda}{2}a$$
Plug this into $g(\omega)=b$ to find $\lambda$: 
$$\left \langle a, x+\frac{\lambda}{2}a  \right\rangle = b$$
hence $ \langle a,x\rangle+\frac{\lambda}{2} |a|^2=b$, and the rest is routine.

Comment: Thank you very much, I just needed to define $f(\omega)=||x-\omega||^2$!